# How to Give everyone read and write access to a pubsub feed

Tags: iphone, xmpp, publish-subscribe, user-permissions

I want to give everyone who subscribes to a node the ability to both read and write to that node.
Joe created the node "test5" in the code below.  When Mark tries to post, I get an error.

I am using XMPPFramework for iphone. I receive the following error IQ. It appears that openfire is telling me that I can't publish an item b/c I don't have access?  What is the default access model, open?

Doesn't that mean that anyone can subscribe to the node "test5", and anyone can publish items to it?

The JID of the fake user who originally created node "tes5" is "mark@joes-macbook-air.local"

Could the unauthorized message posting be b/c mark is not the owner of node titled "test5"?

What if I want mark to be able to post to this feed as well?

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" from="pubsub.joes-macbook-air.local" to="joe@joes-macbook-air.local/838f75ba"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">

<publish node="test5"><item><body>Helpl me</body></item></publish>

</pubsub><error code="403" type="auth">

<forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>

</error>

</iq>
```

Update: I made the subscriber a "publisher". This is done by altering the publish_model of the node.

Comment: It really depends on the XMPP server you are using, the version, and possibly the pubsub module configuration.

Comment: Hi Mickael, I have same requirement. Is there any way to achieve this and What should  be pub sub module configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the node configurations in your pubsub service. Particularly the access mode of your node. In the XEP-0060 the access models section gives a good explanation on the different access methods. ([1](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#accessmodels)) The one you need in your case will be the "Open" which is defined as "Any entity may subscribe to the node (i.e., without the necessity for subscription approval) and any entity may retrieve items from the node (i.e., without being subscribed); this SHOULD be the default access model for generic pubsub services."

I hope this gives a clear answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Future2020, This is not working as required,  We have given access 'open' but not every subscriber able to publish. Any way to achieve this.